# How can I open the breadcrumbs dropdown using only the keyboard in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In VS Code, Is there a way to open up the file selector dropdown, i.e. this:
[image: dropdown_example]

with just the keyboard- such that I will be able to use the arrow keys + enter to switch files?

Comment: use `Ctrl+P` and type part of the file name

Comment: @rioV8 note: I think they're referring to the breadcrumbs dropdown.

Comment: @user but then the question is which breadcrumb dropdown, with `Ctrl+P` you have the whole workspace in one go, not very likely that a particular filename is used often in the same workspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the breadcrumbs using the keyboard, you can use the following commands (in the command palette, or use the corresponding keybinding):

- `Focus Breadcrumbs` (On Windows and Linux, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>. On macOS, use <kbd>cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>). You can then use the arrow keys and the enter and escape keys to navigate.
- `Focus and Select Breadcrumbs` (On Windows and Linux, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. On macOS, use <kbd>cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>). You can then use the arrow keys to navigate.

[Corresponding source code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/browser/parts/editor/breadcrumbsControl.ts) (ctrl+f for "register2").

Comment: why did the OP not search for `breadcrumb` in the keybind GUI

Comment: @rioV8 possibly they didn't know of the terminology. see the revision history of their question post. I edited it for disambiguation and searchability while trying to retain their original keywords in the post body.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings>keyboard shortcuts
then search for "Focus on File Explorer" and put any keybinding (e.g. ctrl+alt+f) as you like to go to file explorer and then you can navigate through the files using keyboard arrow keys.